# What's the syntax for using C#12 collection expressions to initialise a List<List>>?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, collection-initializer, c#-12.0

Say I have code like this (or any kind of jagged structure):

```
var intListList = new List<List<int>> {
    new() { 1, 2, 3 }
};
```

I'd like to use a collection expression here. Resharper (EAP) suggests this:

```
var intListList = new List<List<int>> {
    [1, 2, 3]
};
```

But that doesn't compile.

This must be possible! What's the syntax?

Edit:

OK. So from the answers, instead of this, declaring the type in the expression:

```
// does not compile
var intListList = new List<List<int>> {
    [1, 2, 3]
};
```

The type has to be declared explicitly, and there is no `new()`:

```
// compiles!
List<List<int>> intListList = [[1, 2, 3]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax used for the jagged arrays from the [What's new in C# 12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions):

```cs
// Create a jagged 2D array:
int[][] twoD = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

Seems to work for lists also:

```
List<List<int>> list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

[Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1J72Cf)

Answer (score 7):

Since this is tagged C#12, I believe you could be looking for

```
List<List<int>> list = [[1,2,3]];
```